# How to write a contains method in Java in linkedlist?

Tags: java, linked-list, contains

I've been having trouble in making a code that is supposed to find an element in a linked list and if it is found it returns true and false if not.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.LinkedList; 
  
class LinkedListDemo { 
private static LinkedList<Integer> list;
   public static void main(String args[]) { 
  
      list = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);  
     
      list.add(10); 
      list.add(21); 
      list.add(32); 
      list.add(43); 
      list.add(54); 
  
     
      System.out.println("LinkedList:" + list); 
  
     
      System.out.println("\nDoes the List contains '10': " + search(10)); 
      
  
   }
   public static boolean search(int i) {
    if (list.equals(i)) {
        return true;
}
    else return false;
   }
}
```

I can use the contains method provided in the linkedlist package but I want to be able to create my own method that does the same thing. Also my method always returns false and I cant seem to figure out why

Comment: You should ask 1 question per question. If you have not working code, write up a [mcve] about that. If you have trouble implementing a specific feature, only write about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always returning false because `list` is a `List` and `i` is an `int`, so they can't be equal, since they aren't the same type.

You probably want to wrap a for loop around your search body

```
public static boolean search(int i) {
    for(int item : list)
        if(item == i) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thank for this great help!